# Anova: Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to do anova. However, I always get this—— "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

```r
> class(data$Income)
[1] "integer"
> class(data$region)
[1] "factor"
> trt=data$region
> fit=lm(data$Income~trt)
> anova(fit,trt,console=TRUE)
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: Why do you need `trt` or `console` in the `anova` call? They are not arguments of `anova`. Just run `anova(fit)` and it will work.

Comment: try use dput function to see how your data looks like. for instance for the dataset mtcars you can do dput(mtcars) and copy and paste the output so it will run in our computers and we can test it for bugs

Comment: fit=lm(Income~trt,data=data)

Comment: then do summary(fit)

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos thanks! I tried your code, and it worked well~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fit=lm(Income~trt,data=data)
summary(fit)
```